# Añadir eventos en jsCalendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

Buscando entre varios *plugins* de calendarios, encontré uno llamado jsCalendar por [GramThanos](https://github.com/GramThanos/jsCalendar).

Existe entre sus demos una vista llamada [*Date Events*](https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/demos/date%20events.html), **la cual me parece perfecta para lo que necesito: Saludar según el día a las personas que están de cumpleaños.**

Pero por más que busco en su [documentación oficial](https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/docs.html) no veo como añadir uno o más eventos a un determinado día.

Con JS se agregan eventos predefinidos con la función `onclick`, se muestran en una alerta y se insertan temporalmente:

```
// Add events
                calendar.onDateClick(function(event, date){
                    // Update calendar date
                    calendar.set(date);
                    // Show events
                    showEvents(date);
                });

                elements.addButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

 // Get event name
                    var names = ["John", "Bob", "Anna", "George", "Harry", "Jack", "Alexander"];
                    var name = prompt(
                        "Event info",
                        names[Math. floor(Math.random() * names.length)] + "'s birthday."
                    );
```

¿Puedo añadir eventos manualmente en este *plugin*, o es simplemente visual?

Hace un tiempo utilicé [fullcalendar.js](https://fullcalendar.io/) y podía hacerlo importando mis eventos de Google Calendar de forma automática, pero si debo hacerlo de forma manual no tengo problema.

> PD: En el ejemplo de Date Events se puede editar los eventos, NO deseo que se puedan modificar del lado del usuario.

Acepto cualquier sugerencia o si existen otras alternativas, bienvenidas sean.

Gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solo dale play y mira los comentarios en el código, es lo que estás buscando. Revisa Febrero 12 y Febrero 21.

```js
// Get elements
   var elements = {
    // Calendar element
    calendar : document.getElementById("events-calendar"),
    // Input element
    events : document.getElementById("events")
   }

   // Create the calendar
   elements.calendar.className = "clean-theme";
   var calendar = jsCalendar.new(elements.calendar);

   // Create events elements
   elements.title = document.createElement("div");
   elements.title.className = "title";
   elements.events.appendChild(elements.title);
   elements.subtitle = document.createElement("div");
   elements.subtitle.className = "subtitle";
   elements.events.appendChild(elements.subtitle);
   elements.list = document.createElement("div");
   elements.list.className = "list";
   elements.events.appendChild(elements.list);
   elements.actions = document.createElement("div");
   elements.actions.className = "action";
   elements.events.appendChild(elements.actions);
   elements.addButton = document.createElement("input");
   elements.addButton.type = "button";
   elements.addButton.value = "Add";
   elements.actions.appendChild(elements.addButton);

   var events = {};
   var date_format = "DD/MM/YYYY";
   var current = null;

   var showEvents = function(date){
    // Date string
    var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(date, date_format, "en");
    // Set date
    current = new Date(date.getTime());
    // Set title
    elements.title.textContent = id;
    // Clear old events
    elements.list.innerHTML = "";
    // Add events on list
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(id) && events[id].length) {
     // Number of events
     elements.subtitle.textContent = events[id].length + " " + ((events[id].length > 1) ? "events" : "event");

     var div;
     var close;
     // For each event
     for (var i = 0; i < events[id].length; i++) {
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "event-item";
      div.textContent = (i + 1) + ". " + events[id][i].name;
      elements.list.appendChild(div);
      close = document.createElement("div");
      close.className = "close";
      close.textContent = "×";
      div.appendChild(close);
      close.addEventListener("click", (function (date, index) {
       return function () {
        removeEvent(date, index);
       }
      })(date, i), false);
     }
    } else {
     elements.subtitle.textContent = "No events";
    }
   };

   var removeEvent = function (date, index) {
    // Date string
    var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(date, date_format, "en");

    // If no events return
    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
     return;
    }
    // If not found
    if (events[id].length <= index) {
     return;
    }

    // Remove event
    events[id].splice(index, 1);

    // Refresh events
    showEvents(current);

    // If no events uncheck date
    if (events[id].length === 0) {
     calendar.unselect(date);
    }
   }

   // Show current date events
   showEvents(new Date());

   // Add events
   calendar.onDateClick(function(event, date){
    // Update calendar date
    calendar.set(date);
    // Show events
    showEvents(date);
   });

   elements.addButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Get event name
    var names = ["John", "Bob", "Anna", "George", "Harry", "Jack", "Alexander"];
    var name = prompt(
     "Event info",
     names[Math. floor(Math.random() * names.length)] + "'s birthday."
    );

    //Return on cancel
    if (name === null || name === "") {
     return;
    }

    // Date string
    var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(current, date_format, "en");

    // If no events, create list
    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
     // Select date
     calendar.select(current);
     // Create list
     events[id] = [];
    }

    // Add event
    events[id].push({name : name});

    // Refresh events
    showEvents(current);
   }, false);
      
      //Agregando elementos de manera dinamica:
      //Cumpleaños de Lucía, Febrero 12
      var luciaBirthday = new Date(2019, 1, 12); //Ese 1 es porque en JavaScript, los meses comienzan en CERO = Enero.
      //Cumpleaños de Mily, Febrero 21
      var milyBirthday = new Date(2019, 1, 21);
      //Cumpleaños de Angie, Febrero 24
      var angieBirthday = new Date(2019, 1, 24);
     cargarMensaje(luciaBirthday, "Cumple de Luuuuu!!!");
     cargarMensaje(milyBirthday, "Cumple de Milyyyy!!!");
     cargarMensaje(angieBirthday , "Cumple de Angieee!!!");
      
      function cargarMensaje(fecha, mensaje){
       var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(fecha, date_format, "en");      
        // If no events, create list
    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
     // Select date
     calendar.select(current);
     // Create list
     events[id] = [];
    }
         events[id].push({name : mensaje});
            // Refresh events: Mostramos los eventos del día actual.
     showEvents(current);
      }
```

```css
   html, body {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
   }
   .description {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
   }
   .jsCalendar.clean-theme tbody td.jsCalendar-previous, .jsCalendar.clean-theme tbody td.jsCalendar-next {
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.2;
   }
   #wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   }
   #wrapper .jsCalendar table {
    box-shadow: none;
   }
   .clear {
    clear: both;
   }
   #events-calendar {
    float: left;
   }
   #events {
    float: left;
    width: 435px;
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 5px;
   }
   #events .title {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   }
   #events .subtitle {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #888;
   }
   #events .list {
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
   #events .list .event-item {
    line-height: 24px;
    min-height: 24px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
   #events .list .event-item .close {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #F44336;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   #events .action {
    text-align: right;
   }
   #events .action input {
    padding: 0px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s;
   }
   #events .action input:hover {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
   .version {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: right;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/js/jsCalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/css/jsCalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/css/themes/jsCalendar.clean.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <!-- Calendar element -->
   <div id="events-calendar"></div>
   <!-- Events -->
   <div id="events"></div>
   <!-- Clear -->
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Ahora bien, considera tener en cuenta que los cumpleaños siempre van a ser mostrados el año actual. Si colocas la fecha de nacimiento del evento, sólo podrá ser visto en ese año, esto quizás sea obvio, sin embargo hay muchos programadores que recién están empezando y entre más ideas tengan, mejor les resultará. Saludos :D

Comment: Hasta el momento no he implementado tu respuesta en el campo real, pero veo que funciona con los dos ejemplos que añadiste en el código. Quisiera que estos eventos no se puedan modificar por el usuario (añadir y eliminar); yo podría ocultarlos o eliminarlos desde HTML y/o CSS, pero creo que no sería una buena práctica, lamentablemente no conozco suficiente JavaScript. ¿Podrías indicarme como limpiar estas acciones del código JS?

Comment: Vamos por partes: 1) " Quisiera que estos eventos no se puedan modificar por el usuario (añadir y eliminar)" En el front, TODO puede ser modificado por el usuario, basta con dar click derecho, inspeccionar elemento y ponerte a jugar con los valores y el CSS.

Comment: 2) "¿Podrías indicarme como limpiar estas acciones del código JS?" Borra los event listeners: `elements.addButton.addEventListener` y `close.addEventListener(`

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo fredyfx, voy a aplicar tus recomendaciones a mi código para ver cómo me va y regreso.

Comment: 3) " no conozco suficiente JavaScript." Eso jamás debe ser una limitante, debe evitarse en lo posible decirlo, la respuesta simple: estudiar y practicar. Quienes siempre usan esa frase "es que no sé", se están poniendo un freno, es una excusa que los mantiene exactamente donde están, ¿quieres aprender? hazlo, aquí en la hermandad de SOes nos apoyamos entre todos, revisa este link para que aprendas Javascript http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javascriptya/ en inglés hay un buen sitio: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm disfruta el aprendizaje bro :D

Comment: de nada bro, todos empezamos en algún lado, conforme aprendas, enseña, aprenderás el doble y le harás un bien a la sociedad :D

Comment: Respecto a tu punto 3, tienes razón en lo que siempre debemos buscar respuestas. La pregunta original la hice aquí en el sitio hace aprox. 2 meses, al no encontrar respuesta y sentirme impotente, me inscribí a un curso en la plataforma de Platzi sobre JS, llevo 3 semanas y he aprendido mucho, por desgracia, me queda mucho camino aún para dominarlo en un nivel medio/alto, pero en algún momento lo lograré. EDIT: Gracias por los links, ten por seguro que los voy a revisar y tomar en cuenta!

Comment: Paciencia, perseverancia, disciplina y determinación. Te presento a tu nueva biblia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn PD: Prefiero otras plataformas para estudiar online, Pluralsight es la mejor que hay en la red o una de las mejores a nivel mundial, el único detalle: está en inglés. Si deseas te ayudo a conseguir 3 meses gratis en dicha plataforma :D

Comment: Hola fredyfx, te cuento que probando tu código me encuentro con un problema, los eventos del día actual no se cargan de forma automática, tengo que darles clic al día para que se visualicen, ¿Sabes a qué se deba?

Comment: Lo reviso en la noche que llegue a casa :)

Comment: @AMCode hice una edición y está funcionando. Sólo se tenía que agregar el evento de refresh, en el código hay una función llamada "showEvents". Te recomiendo que todo código que veas, te des unos minutos en analizar, la respuesta estaba en el mismo código; entre más rápido te acostumbres a ello, más fácil será programar para ti. Buena suerte bro :D

Comment: Después de varias pruebas, retoques y limpieza y forzando el código a resistir fallas (más que todo de mi parte jajaja) puedo decir que tiene el comportamiento adecuado. Ya organicé cómo escribir manualmente los eventos, ahora sólo queda armarme de paciencia para crear 365 eventos y asignarles más de mil _strings_. Mil gracias por tu apoyo, tu tiempo y tu paciencia.

Comment: de nada bro, masbien, intenta generarlos dinámicamente, que alguna función te devuelve un json con el mes, el día  y el nombre del cumpleañero/a, te sugiero que muestres al inicio sólo los del día correspondiente y que los demás vayan cargando de acuerdo al día en que se hace click.

Answer (score 2):

No hay nada de mágico con los eventos, simplemente es una variable de arreglo cuyo indice es la fecha, corre el ejemplo de la documentacion oficial y depuralo en el navegador para que examines la variable events. Puedes manipular dicha variable agregando mas eventos de la siguiente forma:

```
events[id].push({name : datos});
```

Lo cual lo hace dentro del disparador de eventos de pulsar el boton Add elements.addButton.addEventListener("click", function()

Ahora bien si te fijas en la documentacion oficial de jscalendar para eliminar eventos simple y llanamente se sigue trabajando con la variable de arreglo:

```
events[id].splice(index, 1);
```

Esto ultimo se ve en var removeEvent = function (date, index)

Comment: Gracias caballero por su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
  // Get elements
   var elements = {
    // Calendar element
    calendar : document.getElementById("events-calendar"),
    // Input element
    events : document.getElementById("events")
   }

   // Create the calendar
   elements.calendar.className = "clean-theme";
   var calendar = jsCalendar.new(elements.calendar);

   // Create events elements
   elements.title = document.createElement("div");
   elements.title.className = "title";
   elements.events.appendChild(elements.title);
   elements.subtitle = document.createElement("div");
   elements.subtitle.className = "subtitle";
   elements.events.appendChild(elements.subtitle);
   elements.list = document.createElement("div");
   elements.list.className = "list";
   elements.events.appendChild(elements.list);
   elements.actions = document.createElement("div");
   elements.actions.className = "action";
   elements.events.appendChild(elements.actions);
   elements.addButton = document.createElement("input");
   elements.addButton.type = "button";
   elements.addButton.value = "Agregar";
   elements.actions.appendChild(elements.addButton);

   var events = {};
   var date_format = "DD/MM/YYYY";
   var current = null;

   var showEvents = function(date){
    // Date string
    var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(date, date_format, "es");
    // Set date
    current = new Date(date.getTime());
    // Set title
    elements.title.textContent = id;
    // Clear old events
    elements.list.innerHTML = "";
    // Add events on list
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(id) && events[id].length) {
     // Number of events
     elements.subtitle.textContent = events[id].length + " " + ((events[id].length > 1) ? "events" : "event");

     var div;
     var close;
     // For each event
     for (var i = 0; i < events[id].length; i++) {
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "event-item";
      div.textContent = (i + 1) + ". " + events[id][i].name;
      elements.list.appendChild(div);
      close = document.createElement("div");
      close.className = "close";
      close.textContent = "×";
      div.appendChild(close);
      close.addEventListener("click", (function (date, index) {
       return function () {
        removeEvent(date, index);
       }
      })(date, i), false);
     }
    } else {
     elements.subtitle.textContent = "No events";
    }
   };

   var removeEvent = function (date, index) {
    // Date string
    var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(date, date_format, "es");

    // If no events return
    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
     return;
    }
    // If not found
    if (events[id].length <= index) {
     return;
    }

    // Remove event
    events[id].splice(index, 1);

    // Refresh events
    showEvents(current);

    // If no events uncheck date
    if (events[id].length === 0) {
     calendar.unselect(date);
    }
   }

   // Show current date events
   showEvents(new Date());

   // Add events
   calendar.onDateClick(function(event, date){
    // Update calendar date
    calendar.set(date);
    // Show events
    showEvents(date);
   });

   elements.addButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Get event name
    var names = ["David", "Bob", "Ana", "Jorge", "Harry", "Jack", "Alexander"];
    var name = prompt(
     "Event info",
     names[Math. floor(Math.random() * names.length)] + " Cumpleaños."
    );

    //Return on cancel
    if (name === null || name === "") {
     return;
    }

    // Date string
    var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(current, date_format, "en");

    // If no events, create list
    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
     // Select date
     calendar.select(current);
     // Create list
     events[id] = [];
    }

    // Add event
    events[id].push({name : name});

    // Refresh events
    showEvents(current);
   }, false);
```

```css
 html, body {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
   }
   .description {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
   }
   .jsCalendar.clean-theme tbody td.jsCalendar-previous, .jsCalendar.clean-theme tbody td.jsCalendar-next {
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.2;
   }
   #wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   }
   #wrapper .jsCalendar table {
    box-shadow: none;
   }
   .clear {
    clear: both;
   }
   #events-calendar {
    float: left;
   }
   #events {
    float: left;
    width: 435px;
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 5px;
   }
   #events .title {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   }
   #events .subtitle {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #888;
   }
   #events .list {
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
   #events .list .event-item {
    line-height: 24px;
    min-height: 24px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
   #events .list .event-item .close {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #F44336;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   #events .action {
    text-align: right;
   }
   #events .action input {
    padding: 0px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s;
   }
   #events .action input:hover {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/css/jsCalendar.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/css/themes/jsCalendar.clean.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/js/jsCalendar.min.js"></script>

<!-- DEFINIENDO TU CALENDAR -->
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Calendar -->
  <div id="events-calendar"></div>
  <!-- Eventos -->
  <div id="events"></div>
</div>
```

Primero en el HTML cargo las librerias por defecto de JsCalendar , acto seguido defino mi HTML tambien se agregara un poco de CSS para darle mejor apariencia a la opcion de agregar eventos que se construye en un div.

En el JavaScript lo que hago es definir mi Jscalendar, tambien se crea un listado por defecto de eventos aletorios prefinidos , los mismos pueden ser obviados, al dar click en boton agregar me saldra un input para agregar el nombre del evento, lo agrego y puedo cambiar entre fechas y se mantendra mis eventos realizados... es una guia basica espero te sirva. [Aca puedes verlo](https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/demos/date%20events.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo Diego, pero creo que lo que me enseñas es lo que actualmente tengo. A lo mejor no me hice entender bien, me excuso por eso.