# Escapar código HTML en evento dinámico de calendario

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Esta pregunta se basa en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/240333/109595).

---

Buen día,

Estoy trabajando con el calendario [JsCalendar de GramThanos](https://github.com/GramThanos/jsCalendar), en su momento necesitaba añadir eventos dinámicos dentro del calendario, con la ayuda del usuario [@fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) se logró de la siguiente manera:

```
//Agregando elementos de manera dinamica:
var pepito = new Date(2020, 0, 23);
var juana = new Date(2020, 0, 24);
var luis = new Date(2020, 0, 25);
var diana = new Date(2020, 0, 26);

cargarMensaje(pepito, "Pepito Perez - Ingeniero");
cargarMensaje(juana, "Juana Diaz - Profesora");
cargarMensaje(luis, "Luis Lopez - Médico");
cargarMensaje(diana, "Diana Jiménez - Científica");

function cargarMensaje(fecha, mensaje) {
  var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(fecha, date_format, "es");
  // If no events, create list
  if (!events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    // Select date
    calendar.select(current);
    // Create list
    events[id] = [];
  }
  events[id].push({
    name: mensaje
  });
  // Refresh events: Mostramos los eventos del día actual.
  showEvents(current);
}
```

Ahora me surge  la necesidad de que esas líneas de texto o entradas reconozcan código HTML, por ejemplo:

```
cargarMensaje(pepito, "<b>Pepito Perez</b> - <i>Ingeniero</i>");
```

Debería aplicarse negrita al nombre y una cursiva a la profesión, pero no se están tomando estos valores y la información mostrada en pantalla es textual la línea:

```
<b>Pepito Perez</b> - <i>Ingeniero</i>
```

Intenté en su momento con jQuery haciendo uso de `$.parseHTML(mensaje);` y luego reemplazando `events[id].push({name : mensaje});` por `events[id].push({name : nuevoMensaje});`

Pero me salían los eventos con el texto `[object text]`

---

Comparto a continuación el código completo, los eventos están en los días 23 a 26 de enero.

Muchas gracias

```js
// Get elements
var elements = {
  // Calendar element
  calendar: document.getElementById("events-calendar"),
  // Input element
  events: document.getElementById("events")
}

// Create the calendar
elements.calendar.className = "clean-theme";
var calendar = jsCalendar.new(elements.calendar);

// Create events elements
elements.title = document.createElement("div");
elements.title.className = "title";
elements.events.appendChild(elements.title);
elements.subtitle = document.createElement("div");
elements.subtitle.className = "subtitle";
elements.events.appendChild(elements.subtitle);
elements.list = document.createElement("div");
elements.list.className = "list";
elements.events.appendChild(elements.list);
elements.actions = document.createElement("div");
elements.actions.className = "action";
elements.events.appendChild(elements.actions);
elements.addButton = document.createElement("input");
elements.addButton.type = "button";
elements.addButton.value = "Add";
elements.actions.appendChild(elements.addButton);

var events = {};
var date_format = "DD/MM/YYYY";
var current = null;

var showEvents = function(date) {
  // Date string
  var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(date, date_format, "es");
  // Set date
  current = new Date(date.getTime());
  // Set title
  elements.title.textContent = id;
  // Clear old events
  elements.list.innerHTML = "";
  // Add events on list
  if (events.hasOwnProperty(id) && events[id].length) {
    // Number of events
    elements.subtitle.textContent = events[id].length + " " + ((events[id].length > 1) ? "events" : "event");

    var div;
    var close;
    // For each event
    for (var i = 0; i < events[id].length; i++) {
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "event-item";
      div.textContent = (i + 1) + ". " + events[id][i].name;
      elements.list.appendChild(div);
      close = document.createElement("div");
      close.className = "close";
      close.textContent = "×";
      div.appendChild(close);
      close.addEventListener("click", (function(date, index) {
        return function() {
          removeEvent(date, index);
        }
      })(date, i), false);
    }
  } else {
    elements.subtitle.textContent = "No events";
  }
};

// Show current date events
showEvents(new Date());

// Add events
calendar.onDateClick(function(event, date) {
  // Update calendar date
  calendar.set(date);
  // Show events
  showEvents(date);
});



//Agregando elementos de manera dinamica:
var pepito = new Date(2020, 0, 23);
var juana = new Date(2020, 0, 24);
var luis = new Date(2020, 0, 25);
var diana = new Date(2020, 0, 26);

cargarMensaje(pepito, "Pepito Perez - Ingeniero");
cargarMensaje(juana, "Juana Diaz - Profesora");
cargarMensaje(luis, "Luis Lopez - Médico");
cargarMensaje(diana, "Diana Jiménez - Científica");

function cargarMensaje(fecha, mensaje) {
  var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(fecha, date_format, "es");
  // If no events, create list
  if (!events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    // Select date
    calendar.select(current);
    // Create list
    events[id] = [];
  }
  events[id].push({
    name: mensaje
  });
  // Refresh events: Mostramos los eventos del día actual.
  showEvents(current);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

.description {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.jsCalendar.clean-theme tbody td.jsCalendar-previous,
.jsCalendar.clean-theme tbody td.jsCalendar-next {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#wrapper .jsCalendar table {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#events-calendar {
  float: left;
}

#events {
  float: left;
  width: 435px;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 5px;
}

#events .title {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#events .subtitle {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
}

#events .list {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#events .list .event-item {
  line-height: 24px;
  min-height: 24px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#events .list .event-item .close {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F44336;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#events .action {
  text-align: right;
}

#events .action input {
  padding: 0px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#events .action input:hover {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/js/jsCalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/css/jsCalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/css/themes/jsCalendar.clean.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Calendar element -->
  <div id="events-calendar"></div>
  <!-- Events -->
  <div id="events"></div>
  <!-- Clear -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La solución la tienes modificando una línea.

En el bucle que recorre los eventos y los inserta en el **DOM** a la hora de insertar el cuerpo del mensaje lo estás haciendo a través de `node.textContent`, lo que provoca que el contenido sea tratado como un literal, ocasionando que cualquier etiqueta quede libre de que el intérprete lo considere código que interpretar como **HTML**.

> La propiedad textContent de la interfaz Node representa el contenido
>   de texto de un nodo y sus dencendientes.

Cambiando el uso de esa propiedad por `innerHTML` lo que consigues es insertar código susceptible a ser interpretado, consiguiendo lo que te propones.

```js
// Get elements
var elements = {
  // Calendar element
  calendar: document.getElementById("events-calendar"),
  // Input element
  events: document.getElementById("events")
}

// Create the calendar
elements.calendar.className = "clean-theme";
var calendar = jsCalendar.new(elements.calendar);

// Create events elements
elements.title = document.createElement("div");
elements.title.className = "title";
elements.events.appendChild(elements.title);
elements.subtitle = document.createElement("div");
elements.subtitle.className = "subtitle";
elements.events.appendChild(elements.subtitle);
elements.list = document.createElement("div");
elements.list.className = "list";
elements.events.appendChild(elements.list);
elements.actions = document.createElement("div");
elements.actions.className = "action";
elements.events.appendChild(elements.actions);
elements.addButton = document.createElement("input");
elements.addButton.type = "button";
elements.addButton.value = "Add";
elements.actions.appendChild(elements.addButton);

var events = {};
var date_format = "DD/MM/YYYY";
var current = null;

var showEvents = function(date) {
  // Date string
  var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(date, date_format, "es");
  // Set date
  current = new Date(date.getTime());
  // Set title
  elements.title.textContent = id;
  // Clear old events
  elements.list.innerHTML = "";
  // Add events on list
  if (events.hasOwnProperty(id) && events[id].length) {
    // Number of events
    elements.subtitle.textContent = events[id].length + " " + ((events[id].length > 1) ? "events" : "event");

    var div;
    var close;
    // For each event
    for (var i = 0; i < events[id].length; i++) {
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "event-item";
      div.innerHTML = (i + 1) + ". " + events[id][i].name; //Esta es la linea modificada
      elements.list.appendChild(div); 
      close = document.createElement("div");
      close.className = "close";
      close.textContent = "×";
      div.appendChild(close);
      close.addEventListener("click", (function(date, index) {
        return function() {
          removeEvent(date, index);
        }
      })(date, i), false);
    }
  } else {
    elements.subtitle.textContent = "No events";
  }
};

// Show current date events
showEvents(new Date());

// Add events
calendar.onDateClick(function(event, date) {
  // Update calendar date
  calendar.set(date);
  // Show events
  showEvents(date);
});



//Agregando elementos de manera dinamica:
var pepito = new Date(2020, 0, 23);
var juana = new Date(2020, 0, 24);
var luis = new Date(2020, 0, 25);
var diana = new Date(2020, 0, 26);

cargarMensaje(pepito, "<b>Pepito Perez</b> - <i>Ingeniero</i>");
cargarMensaje(juana, "Juana Diaz - Profesora");
cargarMensaje(luis, "Luis Lopez - Médico");
cargarMensaje(diana, "Diana Jiménez - Científica");

function cargarMensaje(fecha, mensaje) {
  var id = jsCalendar.tools.dateToString(fecha, date_format, "es");
  // If no events, create list
  if (!events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    // Select date
    calendar.select(current);
    // Create list
    events[id] = [];
  }
  events[id].push({
    name: mensaje
  });
  // Refresh events: Mostramos los eventos del día actual.
  showEvents(current);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

.description {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.jsCalendar.clean-theme tbody td.jsCalendar-previous,
.jsCalendar.clean-theme tbody td.jsCalendar-next {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#wrapper .jsCalendar table {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

#events-calendar {
  float: left;
}

#events {
  float: left;
  width: 435px;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 5px;
}

#events .title {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#events .subtitle {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
}

#events .list {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#events .list .event-item {
  line-height: 24px;
  min-height: 24px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#events .list .event-item .close {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F44336;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#events .action {
  text-align: right;
}

#events .action input {
  padding: 0px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#events .action input:hover {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/js/jsCalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/css/jsCalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://gramthanos.github.io/jsCalendar/css/themes/jsCalendar.clean.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Calendar element -->
  <div id="events-calendar"></div>
  <!-- Events -->
  <div id="events"></div>
  <!-- Clear -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: perfecto! gracias por su amable ayuda, me había enfocado en el final del código JS sin ver el momento que mandaba llamar a los eventos