# Mostrar HTML almacenado en MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css

Tengo almacenado en la base de datos estructuras HTML y al recuperarlas se muestra el texto literal en vez de mostrarlo en el formato HTML original. Es decir me muestra:

```
<p>To: Pat</p><p>From: <span style="background-color: rgb(253, 134, 66);">Brenda</span></p>
```

en vez de mostrarlo directamente aplicando los estilos:

```
To:Pat
From: Brenda (esto con el color de fondo)
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que interprete el texto como HTML?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es la cadena que tratas de insertar en el **DOM** y a través de que función de **Javascript** lo estás haciendo?

Comment: Ojo que lo que quieres puede llegar a ser un problema de seguridad, de todas formas, saber con qué código estás mostrando el texto y si el texto está siendo "formateado" en front o backend nos permitirá ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @Vlady En la aplicación lo que hago es almacenar el contenido de un editor de texto basado  en JavaScript execCommand (basado en este https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/JavaScript/3803-Editor-de-texto-con-opciones-basicas.html) en una base de datos MySQL. Al intentar recuperar el texto ya no lo interpreta como HTML sino que me muestra el contenido literal.

Comment: Sí, entendí tu problema, pero como también pidió @phpMyGuel necesitamos saber qué código usas para mostrar el texto, quizás el código "escapeado" se está guardando en la base de datos o es tu backend el que lo formatea, eso no sabemos y poco podemos hacer con lo que nos diste.

Comment: A lo que quería llegar con la pregunta que lanzo en mi comentario es que en algún momento, tu **string** con **HTML** en su interior, se ha de insertar en el **DOM**. Si te está insertando la cadena literal sin ser interpretada es porque estás usando seguramente la propiedad `textContent` (el intérprete no va analizar la cadena, tratándola como un literal ) en vez de `innerHTML` (el intérprete analiza la cadena y de encontrar etiquetas dentro las intrepreta). https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323916/escapar-c%c3%b3digo-html-en-evento-din%c3%a1mico-de-calendario/323922#323922

Answer (score 4):

Como explican en el sitio de stackoverflow en inglés: [How to display HTML tags as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text) tienes dos maneras de hacerlo, la primera reemplazando el caracter menor qué del inicio de la etiqueta así como el caracter mayor qué al final de la etiqueta por su código :

```
'<' se reemplaza por &lt; y '>' por &gt;
```

La segunda es utilizando la función htmlspecialchars() [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
htmlspecialchars('<strong>something</strong>')
```

Saludos.

Comment: Creo que su duda va en sentido inverso, es decir que quiere que le interprete su texto como HTML. Tampoco especifica el lenguaje de backend que está usando.